# Unstable WiFi on Lenovo T440p using Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, 14.10, lenovo

So basically I've wasted the last two days on trying to figure out how to stabilize my WiFi connection. Ethernet works perfectly fine, yet when I try to connect to my wireless network, my laptop stays connected for about 10 seconds, after which it gets trapped in a miserable connect-disconnect loop. Advice would be much appreciated.

The output of the wireless script is as follows:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 06 Apr 2015 18:45 IDT +0300
Booted last: 06 Apr 2015 18:42 IDT +0300
Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-33-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 12:19:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T440p [17aa:220e]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:818b]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:001b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8192ee

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:8761 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

r8192ee               594758  0 
mac80211              660592  1 r8192ee
cfg80211              510218  2 mac80211,r8192ee
wmi                    19193  0 

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.0.0.8  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6af7:28ff:fe34:61e9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18343870 (18.3 MB)  TX bytes:875727 (875.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f0600000-f0620000 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::aeb5:7dff:fe71:5569/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4821 (4.8 KB)  TX bytes:18054 (18.0 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            r8192ee
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    Perla:           Infra, <MAC 'Perla' [AN1]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 80 WPA2
    HOTFiber-A9BA:   Infra, <MAC 'HOTFiber-A9BA' [AN2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2
    vampirB76564:    Infra, <MAC 'vampirB76564' [AN3]>, Freq 2467 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA2
    HOTBOX-6E64:     Infra, <MAC 'HOTBOX-6E64' [AN4]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    HOTBOX-12F6:     Infra, <MAC 'HOTBOX-12F6' [AN5]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    vampir:          Infra, <MAC 'vampir' [AN6]>, Freq 2467 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA2
    bpointer:        Infra, <MAC 'bpointer' [AN7]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 47 WPA WPA2

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.0.0.8
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.0.0.138

    DNS:             10.0.0.138

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/I love Meretz]] (600 root)
[connection] id=I love Meretz | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=I love Meretz | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jerusalem (based on set time zone)

country IN: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (N/A, 20), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (N/A, 20)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[r8192ee]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192ee/r8192ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     046553152F8274C9D21FCAC
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
staging:        Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        27:43:73:00:F8:EE:18:3C:88:11:43:4F:EB:7F:D9:5F:C6:87:82:EC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     5410C94462FA26A0A3F256C
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        27:43:73:00:F8:EE:18:3C:88:11:43:4F:EB:7F:D9:5F:C6:87:82:EC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-33-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     4A525D9D32B0C6D120CA547
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        27:43:73:00:F8:EE:18:3C:88:11:43:4F:EB:7F:D9:5F:C6:87:82:EC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[r8192ee]
debug: 1
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x153a (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x818b (r8192ee)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    4.440569] r8192ee: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.460486] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[    4.460609] r8192ee 0000:03:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.158154] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    6.007283] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    6.160600] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[    6.177261] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[    6.178881] wlan0: authenticated
[    6.180581] wlan0: associate with <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[    6.184171] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[    6.194747] wlan0: associated
[    6.194755] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   27.211404] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC address> lost
[   28.277336] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[   28.310547] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[   28.413142] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 2/3)
[   28.517259] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 3/3)
[   28.621429] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address> timed out

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: I had the same issue with Lenovo Y580. I upgraded the kernel to the next stable LTS. The 3.19 didn't show well, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the modules are in the staging directory, they are probably early releases.  I would try backports

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.xz
tar -xf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.xz
cd ~/backports-3.19-rc1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: Could you add information about what each of the steps mean, or give a reference?